# Are there any other good names for a Front End Tool Kit?

Tags: sass, gulp, frontend, naming-conventions

I am working on a new project and we are setting up our files structure. Our Front End Team will be working closely with our Back End team and there will be a lot of cross over in regards to file assets.

We are building a "Front End Tool Kit" that uses Gulp, Sass, etc. but want to name it something descriptive and succinct. We have decided against "Style Guide" because it comes across as too static.

Are there any other good terms besides "Tool Kit"?

Comment: How about utilities? Includes? Helpers?

Comment: Are you writing your SASS and Gulp files from scratch? Or are you incorporating items from other libraries? Bootstrap for example, is considered a Framework - as it was built "from scratch" and meant to be used roughly as is. If what you're doing is combining multiple tools into one solution, I think "toolkit" makes sense as you're using a set of tools to accomplish a goal.